# Составьте словосочетания так, чтобы четко был обозначен род данных существительных:

Tags: словосочетание

1. Хонсю
2. СНГ
3. Онтарио
4. НИИ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Полноводное  Онтарио (озеро),

гористый Хонсю(остров),

СНГ выступило(содружество),

наш НИИ  - институт(в разг. речи возможен средний род:  разг. наше НИИ, наше гороно).

Answer (score 1):

Род подобных существительных определяется, исходя из того, что это слово обозначает.

Answer (score 0):

По ответам у меня только один вопрос. А давно мы стали домашние задания делать?!

По теме озер. Сколько ни кручу, убедительных примеров найти не могу. Все они среднего рода, если несклоняемы. Конкретно с Онтарио у кого-то, возможно, возможно возникает желание придать ему мужской род из-за сходства с итальянскими мужскими именами: Марио, Антонио и проч. Других объяснений не вижу. И не думаю, что это распространено.

Comment: Во дела... Пока я писал, grumant свалил в месте с ответом. Ну и как его после этого назвать?

Comment: Кого - его? Мое мнение неизменно : могучий полноводный Онтарио. Названия тяготеют к м. или ж. роду. Правила надо корректировать, сто пудов. Высокогорная Титикака - звучит?)))))))